# Javascript/Node.JS forEach loop with Count

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a forEach loop which displays all records for 'communities'. For every 10th record, I want to insert an 'advert record', then continue with the loop of 'communities'.

With my existing code, although the 'advert record' is displayed at record 10, I've found that 'communities record 10' is being skipped/missed out, so it looks like this:
R1 - R2 - R3 - R4 - R5 - R6 - R7 - R8 - R9 - ADVERT AT 10 - R11 - R12

Whereas what I want is this:
R1 - R2 - R3 - R4 - R5 - R6 - R7 - R8 - R9 - ADVERT AT 10 - R10 - R11

Can someone please advise where my code is going wrong?

```
    <div class="index-record-grid-container" id="communityGroupsContainer">
        <% let count = 0; %>
        <% communities.forEach(function(community, i) { %>
            <% count = count+1; %>
            <% if (count === 10) { %>
                <div class="standard-record-container">
                    <div class="standard-ad-container">
                        <h3 class="standard-ad-header">Advertisement</h3>
                        <% promotions.slice(1,2).forEach(promotion => { %>
                            <img class="standard-ad-image lazy" data-src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dcjceb5aj/image/upload/w_400,c_fit,q_auto,f_auto,fl_lossy/<%- promotion.images[0].public_id %>"> 
                        <% }) %> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            <% } else if (count === 20) { %>
                <div class="standard-record-container">
                    <div class="standard-ad-container">
                        <h3 class="standard-ad-header">Advertisement</h3>
                        <% promotions.slice(1,2).forEach(promotion => { %>
                            <img class="standard-ad-image lazy" data-src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dcjceb5aj/image/upload/w_400,c_fit,q_auto,f_auto,fl_lossy/<%- promotion.images[0].public_id %>"> 
                        <% }) %> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            <% } else { %>
                <div class="standard-record-container">
                    <div class="record-grid-container">
                        <div class="box-record-username-row-2">
```

Comment: possible tag - ejs

Comment: don't use `else` ... just output that block all the time

Comment: also can be shortened by using modulus operator `count % 10 === 0`

Comment: @Bravo ah yes that's it, thank you! If you post as answer I can accept the answer

Comment: @Martin - not really worth an answer in my opinion

Comment: @Bravo ok your call... it answered my question, so seems like an answer to me :)